# Reference to local binding declared in enclosing function

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++

Take the following code:

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    auto [a, unused] = [] {
        return std::array<int, 2>{42, 24};
    }();

    [&] {
        return a * 15;
    }();

    (void) unused;
}
```

Do not worry about the `unused` variable, I just want to destructure the array.

The code compiles fine with the latest GCC and MSVC, but Clang [refuses to compile](https://godbolt.org/g/vZcMKQ). Changing the capture list of the lambda does not change anything. Funny enough, setting explicitly `a` in the capture list raise the error that `a is not a variable`.

I am quite sure this is a bug, but I wanted to ask, mainly because AFAIK `a` is a reference to the first element of the array (with the lifetime extended to the `main` scope in this case), not just an `int`, correct me if I am wrong.

## Edit

As you can see from the other question, the problem is that `a` and `unused` are not *variables* (yes, Clang is right!), but *reference names*, which cannot be captured by lambdas. Nevertheless, if you **really** need something like this, you can use a local variable for the lambda, like this:

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    auto [a, unused] = [] {
        return std::array<int, 2>{42, 24};
    }();

    [&, a = a] {
        return a * 15;
    }();

    (void) unused;
}
```

In this case the object is copied, which is fine with trivially copiable objects. In other case you could use something like

```
[&, r = std::ref(uncopiable_obj)] {
    return r.get().do_something();
}();
```

Said that, I do not like these workaround, because they are very unclear and lower the expressiveness of the code. IHMO it is better to use other, cleaner, solutions.

Comment: You should not write you answer as edit in the question but past create an answer and accept it.

Comment: The answer was closed because it was marked as duplicated. I edited because it wasn't exactly clear that the two questions were heavily related.

Comment: Ah sorry didn't see that for some reason.